# Custom event Issue

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, events, event-handling

I created a Class where I run a new process (a CLI external application), that application has their own progressbar, so I pick the progress from the hidden process console to calculate the percentage outside the console, in my class.

Well, What I want to do is to make an event (or something else, an event is just the first I was think usefull) in the Class to return an Integer number which contains the progress percentage (The percentage is an Integer from 0 to 99)

I've read about how to create custom events but I'm very lost trying it, I don't know how to retrieve the integer (the variable Percentage) outside my class to handle it from other class, for example I run a method from my class so I want to handle the process percentage progress in the default "Form1" Class.

This is the code from my custom Class:

```
Public Class CoreConverter

Public Shared Effects As String = String.Empty ' DSP Effects

' <summary>
' Gets or sets the CoreConverter executable path.
' </summary>
Public Shared CoreConverter_Location As String = ".\CoreConverter.exe"
Public Shared CoreConverter As New Process()

Public Shared CoreConverter_Info As New ProcessStartInfo() With { _
              .CreateNoWindow = True, _
              .UseShellExecute = False, _
              .RedirectStandardOutput = True, _
              .RedirectStandardError = True _
}

Public Shared Event Progress As EventHandler

Protected Sub OnProgress()
    RaiseEvent Progress(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
End Sub

Public Shared Sub Run_CoreConverter()

    CoreConverter_Info.FileName = CoreConverter_Location
    CoreConverter_Info.StandardErrorEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode
    CoreConverter_Info.StandardOutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode
    CoreConverter.StartInfo = CoreConverter_Info
    CoreConverter.Start()

    Dim Percentage As Integer = 0

    While Not CoreConverter.HasExited

        If ChrW(CoreConverter.StandardOutput.Read) = "*" Then
            Percentage += 1
            RaiseEvent Progress(Nothing, EventArgs.Empty)
        End If

    End While

   ' MsgBox("end")

End Sub

End Class
```

This is code from Form1 Class

```
Public Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Shown
    AddHandler CoreConverter.Progress, AddressOf Process_Progress
    CoreConverter.Run_CoreConverter(Arguments, blah blah blah)
End Sub

Protected Sub Process_Progress(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    ' MsgBox(e.ToString) ' I want to obtain the Integer percentage but don't know how to
End Sub
```

Notice that I need to use an Addhandler to handle the Progress event, but really I want to to handle it like this else way but I can't do it and I don't know why:

```
Public Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Shown
    CoreConverter.Run_CoreConverter(Arguments, blah blah blah)
End Sub

Protected Sub Process_Progress(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
Handles CoreConverter.Progress
    ' MsgBox(e.ToString) ' I want to obtain the Integer percentage but don't know how to
End Sub
```

So what I can do to solve both problems?

> UPDATE:

Trying to solve it using @varocarbas solution...

CoreConverter Class:

```
Public Shared WithEvents p_progressBar As ProgressBar

Public Shared Sub Run_CoreConverter()

    p_progressBar = New ProgressBar() With {.Maximum = 60}

    CoreConverter_Info.FileName = CoreConverter_Location
    CoreConverter.StartInfo = CoreConverter_Info
    CoreConverter.Start()

    While Not CoreConverter.HasExited

        If ChrW(CoreConverter.StandardOutput.Read) = "*" Then
            p_progressBar.PerformStep()
        End If

    End While

    p_progressBar.Dispose()
    CoreConverter.Close

End Sub
```

Form1 Class:

```
Public Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Shown

    ' Exception: p_progressBar is not an event (of course, I know)
    AddHandler CoreConverter.p_progressBar, AddressOf Process_Progress

    CoreConverter.Run_CoreConverter(arguments, blah blah blah)

End Sub

Sub Process_Progress(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) ' Handles Coreconverter.p_progressBar obviouslly I can't do this... :(
    MsgBox(sender.value)
End Sub
```

Comment: I assumed that there was an event (even more than one) accounting for the value variation of the progressBar (usual proceeding in most of the controls) but, surprisingly, this is not the case with ProgressBar and that's why I have deleted my answer (its point was precisely avoiding to customise anything and just relying on in-built functionalities).

Comment: @Varocabras Just I only will say you that really thanks for try to help and for making good answers. Maybe will be the next time where I can mark your answer to give you some points :P. (And I was relaxed, forgive my english)

Comment: ?! You have already given me points (+1) and I have deleted my answer. Actually I might edit my answer or create a new one with the custom event you are looking for and get the points you are talking about, but not feeling like. For some of us, points are not too important (although I tend to attract quite a few :)), but doing the right thing and helping the right people. You, for example, will not get further help from me in a while, just because today you have done an excellent work to get this award ;)

Comment: I do not understand why you said that you will not bring me more help because that is what I deserve, I think I did anything to you, but if this is kinda some confusion then just is because I need use to use a translator to write/read most of phrases in English. either way thanks again.

Comment: Nothing to do with the English, but with (completely) different attitudes. Anyway... there are plenty of helpers here so you will not feel any difference. Enjoy SO!

Comment: I don't know which attitudes you mean, if you felt offended must have been my mistake by a translation because I respect people, I want to learn from experts programmers like you when someone resolve a problem of mine, and I give points for people who like receive a "thanks" and points. But well, that is your decissión if you feel that my apptitudes are not correct, thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I resolved this by following the steps of marked answer here: [Handle events in another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7285410/handle-events-in-another-class)